# abcpdf html image stretching

Tags: html, image, resolution, dpi, abcpdf

I'm trying to render a html page with an image in it.

I am having an issue that current the size of the image seems to be getting doubled, my image is 304x112 and when it renders to pdf it is 607x224.

I did find this

> Screen resolution is typically 96 dpi. So when you view an HTML page
>   on your monitor, Windows will display it at 96 dpi.
>
> The disparity between the screen resolution and the PDF 72 dpi
>   resolution means that HTML appears larger in print documents than it
>   does on screen.
>
> You will need to apply a scale of 72/96 (0.75) to compensate for this
>   if you want both to appear the same size.
>
> For example, if you are rendering a web page supplying a value of 800
>   for the Width parameter, you will need to set the width of your Rect
>   to 600 if you want both to appear the same size.

and

> PDF documents are predominantly vector-based. As such, they do not
>   really have a dpi because they are resolution independent. The only
>   portions of PDFs which are raster based are images.
>
> Most elements of HTML - text, lines - are vector based. So they are
>   resolution-independent.
>
> The resolution at which images in your web pages are rendered is
>   complicated. Suppose you have a 300 square image referenced by an
>   image tag. If the width of your Doc.Rect is the same as the width you
>   pass to AddImageUrl, then this will be rendered at 72 dpi. However, by
>   changing the ratios between these two values, the image will be scaled
>   and hence the resolution will be changed.
>
> And... if your 300 square is in an img tag with a width and height of
>   150, then the default resolution will be doubled.

My problem seems to be what is described in the second part there.

My end result will be to add the output to a a4 portrait page so it can be printed (along with other text in the document but that is working correctly).

Currently when rendering I use this

```
doc.MediaBox.String = pageSize;
doc.Rect.String = pageSize;
doc.AddImageHtml(html, true, width, disableCache);
```

where page size is "A4" and the width is set to 800 in the addimagehtml call.

I have tried setting the doc.Rect.Width to 600 after the pagesize is set and also made the width to the addimagehtml call 800 but the image still renders incorrectly.

Is there something else I'm missing?

EDIT:
Html of page to be converted is this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head runat="server">
        <title>Workpack</title> 
        <style>
             body { font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body style="border: 1px solid black;">
        <div style="height: 1100px;">
            <div style="position: absolute; top: 50%;">
                <div style="text-align: center; width: 780px;" >
                    <div>
                        <% if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.CompanyLogo)){%>
                            <img src="<%: Url.ToFullyQualifiedUrl(Model.CompanyLogo) %>"/>
                            <% } %>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h1><%: Model.PlantName %></h1>
                    </div>
                    <div style="font-size: 15pt; font-weight: bold;">
                        <h1><%: Model.WorkpackTitle %> - <%: Model.WorkPackNumber %></h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've also tried setting the addimagehtml width and the rect.width both the same to 595 and 800 with no change

Comment: can you not just use the doc.rendering options and set the pdf to be 72 dpi ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the actual HTML it's difficult to say. The basic idea is that `AddImageUrl`/`AddImageHtml` will fill the area of the `Rect`, so to make the image smaller in the final output you can reduce the `Rect` (so that `Rect` is smaller than `MediaBox`).

Alternatively you can reduce the `width` parameter. For example:

```
const string kHtml = "<html><img src='https://encrypted.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png'></html>";

// The img gets smaller and smaller....
foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(1, 5))
{
    using (var doc = new Doc())
    {
        doc.Rect.String = doc.MediaBox.String = "A4";
        doc.AddImageHtml(kHtml, true, 400 * i, true);
        doc.Save(i + ".pdf");
    }
}
```

Comment: I've added the html, its pretty straightforward nothing fancy

Comment: So it should be pretty equivalent to the HTML with Google logo above? If that's the case maybe we can use the simpler HTML for testing. Does running the above code give you the scaling effect so you can counter the image resolution problem?

Comment: looks like it does give me the scaling effect, now to just figure out the correct value to make it look the same size as when viewed on a webpage

Comment: ended up getting it working however I had to make my text bigger as well as everything on the page was scaled down, so the text size is a bit inconsistent with the other pages that haven't had to be scaled the same way as they don't have images.

Comment: @DanielPowell Even though this is quite unexpected, maybe you could simply scale the `<img>` tag itself? Again it could be difficult to tell what's going on but if you send a full isolated test case (with an exe and the HTML + images/CSS) to ABCpdf's support email then possibly a more elegant solution could be found.

Comment: yeah scaling the image tag was my next fallback

Comment: @kizzx2 do you have ide about below issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22069825/abcpdf-not-showing-full-table-data