# ABCPDF not showing full table data

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, abcpdf

Please refer to the image below:

[image]

It's cutting off some of the table data because of the width. My table width is more than 1000 px. I know `The default document size for ABCpdf is 612 by 792.`

Using the code below to set document width and height

```
            double w = doc.MediaBox.Width;
            double h = doc.MediaBox.Height;
            double l = doc.MediaBox.Left;
            double b = doc.MediaBox.Bottom;
            doc.Transform.Rotate(90, l, b);
            doc.Transform.Translate(w, 0);
            doc.Rect.Width = h;
            doc.Rect.Height = w;
```

I want to display all tabular data. Do I need to modify my table size? Or do I need to modify the document page size of the pdf?

How could i resolve this issue?

Thanks,

Siva

Comment: Are you converting an HTML page to PDF?

Comment: yes am converting html page to pdf. how to set browser width to show all tabular data

Comment: Can you provide the html to reproduce this behavior?

Comment: @malkassem  http://jsfiddle.net/lvtrvd/UCBpc/. fiddle contains sample html and css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reviewing the HTML, I think that I can give you a few tips on how to resolve your issue:

1- Use the Gecko Engine for PDF Rendering:

```
doc.HtmlOptions.Engine = WebSupergoo.ABCpdf9.EngineType.Gecko;
```

The Gecko Engine provides better Css compliance when rendering in ABCPdf.

2- In your Css you have `overflow-x` set to `scroll` for the `inner-container`.  This causing the behavior that you are seeing.  I would add the following Css to the bottom of the Css:

```
@media print
{
    .outer-container {
        background-color: #ccc;
        position: absolute;
        top:0;
        left: 0;
        right: 300px;
        bottom:40px;
        overflow: visible;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .inner-container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: relative;
        overflow-x: visible;

    }

    table
    {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Notice the `@media print` which makes the css only effective during print and would not affect that way it shows on the screen.

3-  Finally, you can try playing with the browser width:

```
doc.HtmlOptions.BrowserWidth = 1200;
```

The only problem with the BrowserWidth property is that it will affect the zoom on the document.  All the text fonts will appear smaller.

Good luck...

Comment: Thanks for your prompt respone. Will try ur suggestion once!!

Comment: we can't use default engine(mshtml) for this case ?

Comment: Default engine, might give you different results. Gecko is more compatible with the latest Css.  It is a suggestion, so try it either way and see what would give you the best results.

Comment: Thank you very much !!! after setting value (1200) to browserwidth property, eveything works fine. Is it possible to set width dynamically based upon the table content  ?

Comment: If you can measure the HTML table width and pass it to the function, you probably can.  Otherwise, it might get very tricky.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified if you are converting an HTML page to PDF- but I assume you are. If that is the case, have you looked at the browser width property? Look into the XHTMLOptions object properties- it will help you fine tune the rendering:

http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/source/5-abcpdf/xhtmloptions/

Comment: yes am converting html page to pdf. how to set browser width to show all tabular data