# Remove a .png image from the HTML while rendering it to a .pdf using ABCPDF

Tags: c#, abcpdf

I am using ABCPDF and have a issue where I have hidden a image in my .html page.. but that image appears on the pdf when I render that HTML page to PDF from HTML using the following code

```
 pageID = DR.AddImageHtml(imageURL);

                    while (true)
                    {
                        DR.FrameRect();
                        if (!DR.Chainable(pageID))
                            break;
                        DR.Page = DR.AddPage();
                        pageID = DR.AddImageToChain(pageID);
                    }

                    //Now flatten the layering in the PDF document.
                    for (int i = 1; i <= DR.PageCount; i++)
                    {
                        DR.PageNumber = i;
                        DR.Flatten();
                    }
                    DR.Save(tempFilePath);
```

The image that I talk of is a static image and I need a way to exclude the image from the pdf.

I am pretty new to abcpdf and know almost nothing about it. 
any help is appereciated

Comment: Please add a sample html that you could produce the issue with.

Comment: @malkassem do you have any idea abou this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22069825/abcpdf-not-showing-full-table-data